# How do I create separate Strings from a .txt file using a BufferedReader with char separations? Main concern w format

Tags: string, loops, char, bufferedreader

```
Name1
No
0,0
1,1
2,2
*
Name2
Yes
0,0
1,1
2,2
*
```

The above is the text input formatting, which continues for 100s of names. Alright, so I know how Strings and BRs work, my main concern is how my data input is set up. (sorry this format is weird, something's wonky). So my main goal would be to drag the data set into separate strings, something like "Name1 No 0,0 1,1 2,2" and "Name2 Yes 0,0 1,1 2,2", but I'm having a few issues. The .txt is extremely lengthy, and the only separation in data is the * symbols, and there's a long list of of names (that need to be converted into strings of the same format). I need the reader and string to be able to break at the asterisk and then continue reading until the next, etc etc. 
All I've got currently is

"while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && line.indexOf('*') < 0); "

I'm so lost, as this only reads the first name input. I know it only requires a simple loop, but my mind is strung out on caffeine and I'm in a fix that needs sleep. Any quick ideas?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense. You posted what the input file looks like, but what are you supposed to do with it? From your code, you'll see that the loop will finish the first time you encounter a `*`. You should also tag the question with the language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
String output = "";
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    output += line;
}
String parsedOutput = output.split();
```

You are reading everything into a `String` and then `split` it by defining the `*` to be the separator.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something simple!